# How to autoplay youtube-videos in WebView (ios,Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Autoplay doesn't seem to work for WebView.

Already tried:

```
localWebView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
localWebView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
```

But it just doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to load my website, which contains an embedded youtube livestream, but it only plays if I tap on it. Also it only plays in fullscreen and not inline, even if playInline is used.